# Connection refused running Docker container in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a Docker image in a Amazon EC2 instance. The container started ok on port 8080.

[image]

When I open another termial, and a I run `curl localhost:8080/customers/1`, the terminal shows: **curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: connection refused**.

The instance is associated with a security-group with this configuration:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your `docker run` command?

Comment: @BenWhaley Thank you, yes, I run in this way: **[root@ip-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx ec2-user]# docker run alegallagher11/springaws**
The image is a spring boot application, with the property server.port:8080, and it connects with a RDS AWS.

Comment: You need to map port 8080 to your container. `docker run -p 8080:8080`. Or you can use the IP address of the container (find with `docker inspect`) instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks @BenWhaley ! It works :) !

Comment: using docker run --net=host will simply map the ports if the have the same value.